# Changing mySQL Query to Django

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models

I am having difficulties changing the following MySQL Query to a Django Query

```
SELECT * FROM dashboard_db.dashboard_system ds 
JOIN dashboard_db.dashboard_userpreference up 
ON ds.id = up.system_id
WHERE username = "<user>"
```

Here are the models in my Django application

```
class System(models.Model):
   system_name = models.CharField(max_length = 40)
   LOCATION = (('0', 'Inernal'),('1','External'))
   location = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=LOCATION)

   def __str__(self):
      return self.system_name

class UserPreference(models.Model):
   username = models.CharField(max_length = 40)
   system = models.ForeignKey(System, on_delete = models.CASCADE)

   def __str__(self):
      return self.username
```

I have been trying to use unions and a few other options. I am aware that Performing a raw SQL query is an option. However I was wondering if it is possible to perform the join using a Django styled query.

Comment: So I assume you want the `System`s for which the corresponding `UserPreference` `username` is a given username?

Comment: Yes you are correct. The username is also given

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you want the `System`s for which *at least* one of the corresponding `UserPreference`s `username` is a given `<user>`.

We can do this by querying through the reversed queryset, by using the name of that model, and two consecutive underscores:

```
System.objects.filter(userpreference__username='<user>')
```

where you of course replace `'<user>'` with the string that matches the username (or a Python expression that "calculates" the username you wish to obtain).

This will produce a `QuerySet` that will contain all `System`s for which the condition holds. Note however that some `System`s might occur *multiple* times in case *multiple* `UserProfile`s exist with the given `username` that link to that `System` (perhaps that is here impossible, but since `username` is not `unique=True` in your models, at least from a theoretical perspective, that is possible).

In case you want a `System` to occur *at most* once, you can use `.distinct()` on the `QuerySet`:

```
# systems occur *at most* once
System.objects.filter(userpreference__username='<user>').distinct()
```

Comment: @Haytes: I added a note about the fact that some `System`s migt occur multiple times, and how to avoid that (that might perhaps be of interest to you).

Comment: That was also helpful thanks again for the fast responses.